# Jquery children selection not occuring

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have something like this:

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
  $('.babyitem').fadeToggle('slow', function() {});
});
```

It works in the sense that when an item is hovered, all of the babyitems fade in. However, I just want the specific child .babyitem to fade in.

I have tried this, but nothing happens:

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('.babyitem').fadeToggle('slow', function() {});
});
```

Also the HTML is like this:

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="babyitem">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does a `.item` have a `.babyitem` as a child? What exactly is your markup?

Comment: What you have should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/tQnG8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is .babyitem a direct child of .item ? If it is not, you should consider using .find() instead of .children() :

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.babyitem').fadeToggle('slow', function() {});
});
```

Comment: Hmm it must not be direct the way my actual code is - this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an individual item to fade, give it an id and use "#" instead of  "."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how all your code is setup because the sample is rather small, but would something like this work for you?

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
  $('.babyitem', this).fadeToggle('slow', function() {});
});
```